# Connecting to SQL Server when restarting domain controller

Tags: sql-server, domaincontroller

I have 2 W2k3 domain controllers. Sometimes, when I need to restart one of them, ASP.NET applications cannot connect to SQL Server showing the following exception: "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."

After 30-60 seconds SQL connects to the other domain controller and everything starts to work again.

Is this normal? Is there any way to reduce this downtime?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you restarting sql or just the AD controllers? Are the connections to the app; new or existing?

Comment: I'm only restarting one of the AD controllers. I think connections are available in the ASP.NET connection pool.

Comment: I would expect your connections to be cached; but i think that needs your sql to run on local user accounts not domain / service accounts as they can't do the caching. If that doesnt resolve it the hardware boys on serverfault should be able to give you a better answer.